# Rigid body rolling quesion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image]

Hey, im having a bit of trouble with the problem in the added photo.
So, there is the cylinder which is attached by a massless rope to a massless pulley, to a box (assume it is a pointed object).
Now, Im supposed to find the acceleration (linear) of the cylinder assuming its going down.
So, I know I can write torques and Newton's laws equations but i could not figure out why my professor said that the acceleration of the box (upwards) is twice the size of the linear acceleration of the cylinder.
Can anybody help figure this issue please.

Comment: Is the rope being wrapped around the cylinder?

Comment: That's the answer, then. If the cylinder rolls three inches, the relevant part of the rope is three inches shorter, and the box moves up six inches. So the box travels twice as far, and its velocity and acceleration are twice as large.

Comment: So, you are saying that the velocity of the top edge of the cylinder is equal to the velocity if the box? and because of the velocity if the center mass of the cylinder is half the velocity of the edge its moves with half the acceleration?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the acceleration is zero at the contact point and $a$ at the edge, increasing linearly the acceleration of the centre is $a/2$.

Starting from the linear velocities of various points on the solid, say one at the top edge (let's call it A), the centre (O) and one at the contact point (B), all at a certain time: if the wheel was pinned at the centre $V(A)$ would be $R\omega$ where $\omega$ is the angular velocity of the cylinder; $V(B)$ would be the same and $V(O)$ would be 0. However the contact point is constrained by the ground - as a result, all speeds are offset by $R\omega$ meaning that now $V(A)=2\times V(O)$.

Comment: OK, so i know that v(a) is twice the size of v(o), but the acceleration ratio still ain't clear to me. are you saying that v(a) is equal to the velocity of the box?

Comment: Acceleration is the derivative of speed. And a rope transfers tension, so as long as it is under tension the velocities (neglecting the elasticity of the rope etc.) are equal at each end of the rope. The pulley changes the direction of those end velocities but not their magnitude. So in other words, as long as the weights of each are enough to keep the rope under tension, yes.

Answer (score 1):

If the box moves 1in down, then the edge of the cylinder will move 1in meaning the center will move 0.5in (considering no slipping).

Thats where the factor of 2 comes from.

Comment: What makes you say the center will move half of what the edge has moved? I thought the whole cylinder has just one linear acceleration..

Comment: Isn't the cylinder rolling on the incline? So the edge that is contacting as zero velocity and the outside edge has $v$. The average (center) as $\frac{v}{2}$.

Comment: That i get, but i don't get why is the velocity at the top edge is equal to the velocity of the box..

Comment: Aren't they connected with a rope/string?